# How to check the contents of checkbox array before submit

Tags: php, javascript, arrays, forms, checkbox

I have a php function like this

```
function printSelectedMembers($id) {

    $full_name = $this->getUserName($id);
    echo '<dl>';
    echo '<dt><label for="event_show">Selected member :</label></dt>';
    echo '<input type="checkbox" name="pvtContacts[]"  checked="checked" value="'.$id.'"/>'.$full_name;
    echo '</dl>';
}
```

In this I want to delete the entry if the member is already in the checkbox array ( pvtContacts[] ). How will I check the contents of the array before submitting the form ?

Comment: Php cant check the submit values before submiting. You need to use client side javascript for that.

Comment: Your question is yet unclear. Why don't you test if the member is in the array before creating the html code? And by submitting, do you mean sending the html to the client or do you mean the client submitting the form (i.e. pressing the submit button)?

Comment: @Martin If a member is still in the array I want to delete the member . Actually its a AJAX response form where the user can select members of choice before submitting the form . So if by mistake he selects a user he must be able to delete him . But in my case the member is selected again ! I am using onchange() event .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as in comments you cannot check fields with php, as they are checked after the form is submitted, but you can use javascript to check if checkboxes are checked.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function checkForm(form) { 
    for (i=0; i<form.elements['pvtContacts[]'].length; i++) { 
        // this is where you start the checks or altering the form
        // remove (but you have to setup an unique id for each field):
        // var thisId = document.getElementById(form.elements['pvtContacts[]'][i].id);
        // thisId.parentNode.removeChild(thisId);
        if (form.elements['pvtContacts[]'][i].checked != true) { 
            // no all checkboxes are checked
            return false; 
        } 
    } 
    return true; 
}
</script>
```

you can modify the function to alter/delete some parts ...